# Eigen named access to vector segment

Tags: c++, visual-c++, eigen

I would like to create a custom Eigen vector class which has named references to specific segments (or blocks for matrices). This should allow me to alter specific parts of the vector at once without having to remember the specific indices, which in my opinion leads to more readable code when working with large vectors/matrices. After following some advice in the Eigen documentation I came up with the following demo implementation:

```cpp
#include "Eigen/Core"
#include <iostream>

struct State : public Eigen::Matrix<double,12,1>{
    static constexpr unsigned int SIZE = 12;
    using data_t = Eigen::Matrix<double,SIZE,1>;

    Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Vector3d> pos;// Same problem using Eigen::VectorBlock<data_t,3>
    Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Vector3d> ang;
    Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Vector3d> vel;
    Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Vector3d> ang_vel;

    State(const Eigen::Vector3d& pos, const Eigen::Vector3d& ang, const Eigen::Vector3d& vel, const Eigen::Vector3d& ang_vel)
    : State(){
        this->pos = pos;
        this->ang = ang;
        this->vel = vel;
        this->ang_vel = ang_vel;
    }

    State() : State(data_t::Zero()){}

    // This constructor allows you to construct State from Eigen expressions
    template<typename OtherDerived>
    State(const Eigen::MatrixBase<OtherDerived>& other)
    : data_t(other), pos(this->segment<3>(0)), ang(this->segment<3>(3)), vel(this->segment<3>(6)), ang_vel(this->segment<3>(9)){}

    // This method allows you to assign Eigen expressions to State
    template<typename OtherDerived>
    State& operator=(const Eigen::MatrixBase<OtherDerived>& other)
    {
        this->data_t::operator=(other);
        return *this;
    }
};

State createState(){
    State x;
    x.pos = Eigen::Vector3d(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    return x;
}

int main(){
    State x = createState();
    std::cout << x.pos << std::endl;
    State dx;
    dx.pos = x.pos/2;
    std::cout << dx.pos << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code works perfectly fine in Release mode (with optimizations enabled) and prints

> 1, 1, 1
> 0.5, 0.5, 0.5

However when I turn on Debug mode (without optimizations and added debug symbols) it prints something like

> -9.25596e+61, -9.25596e+61, 0
> -4.62798e+61, -4.62798e+61, -4.62798e+61

I am using MSVC Build tools 2019 on a windows 10 laptop to compile and run this example.
When investigating more closely with the debugger it seems the data in the vector itself is still intact, however the named references are now pointing to different memory locations (dangling pointers). It is also important to note that this behaviour only occurs for a `State` returned by another function. If the `State` is constructed inside the main function, everything works as expected.

I found a solution to this problem which I will describe in an answer below, but wanted to see if someone more familiar with the Eigen internals can explain this and/or come up with a better solution.

**Update:**
I just tested the above code on another computer (Linux) using GCC 6.4.0 and there everything works fine. So it might also be compiler related.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that providing a custom (otherwise default created) copy constructor and move constructor resolves the above issue.

```cpp
State(const State&)
: data_t(other), pos(this->segment<3>(0)), ang(this->segment<3>(3)), vel(this->segment<3>(6)), ang_vel(this->segment<3>(9)){
    // Default copy constructor causes dangling references in debug mode.
}
State(State&& other)
: data_t(std::move(other)), pos(this->segment<3>(0)), ang(this->segment<3>(3)), vel(this->segment<3>(6)), ang_vel(this->segment<3>(9)){
    // Default move constructor causes dangling references in debug mode.
}
```

Because of these changes the compiler complained that the copy assignment operator was deleted by default, hence I needed to add an implementation for this operator as well (this was only necessary in a more elaborate scenario than the simple demo above):

```cpp
State& operator=(const State& other){
    this->data_t::operator=(other);
    return *this;
}
```

For now this works fine for my approach, the drawback however is that I have to repeat the initialization of the named references in three constructors now.